# Send data from Fuse, or a Topic, to Jboss BPM Suite

Tags: jboss, jbpm, jbossfuse, business-process

I would like to send all data received from fuse, in a specific Topic, to a Business Process in BPM Studio. Is there any way?

*Example:
I send a value to 'testTopic' in Fuse. Then Fuse send this value to a Business Process (or the Business Process retrieve it), then the Business Process do things based on the value recevied, like sending another value to another topic*

Is somithing of this kind possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it most definitely is possible, although you would need to route from the 'testTopic' to one of the JMS Queues that jBPM can listen on and transform the message to reflect a valid jBPM command. The generic principle is described in the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#d0e12149. The real power becomes clear when you look at all the jBPM commands you can send in the packages

`org.drools.core.command.runtime.process` (Maven: org.drools:drools-core)

and

`org.jbpm.services.task.commands` (Maven: org.jbpm:jbpm-human-task-core).

When talking from the outside world, it would typically be necessary to identify a correlationKey in the process which is basically the "Business Key" that can be used to identify a process uniquely e.g. as 'ApplicationNumber' for an application process. This can be used to then identify which process you may want to signal/abort/etc.

Since you are working in Fuse you should probably also consider routing that message to the jBPM Rest API described at http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#d0e10088. This may simplify your code a bit because it is a more synchronous API. The drawback however is the REST over HTTP invocation typically does not respect the local transaction.